# Linux command to find a c++ method

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am new on Linux and would like to know the command line that would allow me to have see the interface of the smthg::smthg1::smthg2::smthg3() method in order to see if I am correctly catching an exception.

Comment: I think that's pretty much just the man pages. Otherwise, there's lots of online references.

Comment: You can use the command grep

Comment: You can't tell that from the function's prototype. You'll need to consult the documentation and hope that somebody wrote something correct there.

Comment: ctags, cscope. [clang-completer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the following command to find that :

```
grep -rn "smthg::smthg1::smthg2::smthg3()"
```

It will find the all lines matching the specified pattern.

Edit : One way to know if you catch an exception at runtime, it's to print one message like this :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  try {
    throw 20;
  }catch(int x) {
    cout << "Exception catch with status " << x << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If the message is printed then the exception is catched else it's not.

Comment: thanks it works fine , But how to insure that the exception was correctly catched for exemple the std::exception ?